# Why does var name = 'jose' !== ''; return "true" and not true?

Tags: javascript, string, boolean, comparison

When I run `var name = 'jose' !== '';` in my console, it returns `"true"`

Why does it return `"true"` as a string and not `true` as a boolean?

I tried it with a different variable name and it returns a boolean.
i.e.: `var bobby = 'bob' !== '';`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `name` is `window.name`. A special variable that is always a string. Type it into the console of any empty browser and you will get `""`.

You are reassigning its value in your statement.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: what about bobby in the example above?

Comment: @guradio `var bobby` is a different variable name, so it is not in a String.

Comment: There is no `window.bobby`.

Comment: shouldn't `var name` force it to be local?

Comment: @andrewdotnich Only if it's inside a function--the scope is `window` if it is not inside a function.

Comment: @Jerry right on :)

Answer (score 0):

variable `name` .It refers to window.name, which is the name of the window.

Also variable `document`

> > window.name ,window.document [can't change var name from being window.name, which is a string]

**don't use name as a global variable.**

Eg

```
var name = {Name : "dd"};
console.log(name.Name);//Since it's a primitive won't work
```